# $C=A+B$ diagonalizable $\implies$ $A$ and $B$ simultaneously diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

If $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable matrices, then clearly $A+B$ is diagonalizable. But is the converse true ? i.e if $C=A+B$ is diagonalizable, are $A$ and $B$ simultaneously diagonalizable?

Comment: This would mean if $C$ is diagonalizable and $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ and $C-A$ are simultaneously diagonalizable. You can find many many counter-examples to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any non-diagonalizable matrix $A$ and let $B=-A$. Then $A+B$ is the null matrix, which is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$are not diagonalizable but $A+B$ is diagonal.